# Add class to end of div

Tags: jquery, css, class

I have a div tag labeled

```
<div id = "product-tabs" class="gen-tabs gen-tabs--style1">
```

I need to add accor to the end of the class section

```
gen-tabs gen-tabs--style1 accor
```

Using jQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".product-2-square-furniture-leg").parent(".gen-tabs--style1").addClass(".accor");    
})
```

This will be on a specific page body is `product-2-square-furniture-leg`. Perhaps I have the wrong path?

Comment: Just don't use the `.` when you addClass - you're already specifying that it's a class, so you don't need the dot to specify it agian

Comment: Remove the . from the addClass(".accor").

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `.` (dot) from your class

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".product-2-square-furniture-leg").parent(".gen-tabs--style1").addClass("accor");    
})
```

The `addClass()` already specifies it as a class, you don't need to use the dot when it comes to those things like `hasClass`, `addClass`, `removeClass`

Also, this could just be me, but I like to use `closest()` instead of `parent()` (and `find()` instead of `children()`).  Not sure if that's detrimental to speed or anything, but hey - you're using jQuery, so speed doesn't matter, right?

Comment: after trying and flushing my cache, i can see the javascript but it doesnt seem to work. any ideas?

Comment: in your console, just write `$('.product-2-square-furniture-leg')` and see if it's even recognizing that that specific class exists.  Make sure the spelling is all totally correct?